# How to mock final variable initialized inside constructor ,using EasyMock and PowerMock?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

Below mentioned code is implementation class, Need to mock the final variables inside junit .And to set the required value.

```
public class XyzInterceptor 
    private final int requestLimit;
    private final int responseLimit;
    LimitHealper limitHealper = LimitHealper.getInstance();
    //Constructor
    public XyzInterceptor() {
        requestLimit = limitHealper.getLimits("fff");
        responseLimit = limitHealper.getLimits("fff");
            }
            
        public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) {

        // Check if rate limit is disabled
        if (requestLimit == 0 && responseLimit == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        
        //logic inside
        
        }
}
```

Test Method

```
@Test
    public void preHandelWhenLimitIsavailable() {       
        
        MockHttpServletRequest req = get("/customResource")
                .buildRequest(new MockServletContext());        
              
        MockHttpServletResponse resp = new MockHttpServletResponse();           
            
        XyzInterceptor crrli = PowerMock.createPartialMock(XyzInterceptor.class, "XyzInterceptor");
        EasyMock.expect(limitHealper.getLimits(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class))).andReturn(6000).anyTimes();
        EasyMock.replay(limitHealper);
        crrli.preHandle(req, resp, "doesn't matter");        
        Assert.assertEquals(200,resp.getStatus());
        
    }
```

While running the test  getting below error
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No methods matching the name(s) XyzInterceptor were found in the class hierarchy of class com.xx.xx.xx.xx.XyzInterceptor.

Note : On top of the class i have these annotation
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(XyzInterceptor .class)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added the test code and error which I am getting post run. the two final variable which are populated inside a constructor in the implementation class, need to assigna value from junit so the other logic should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I will heavily advocate for a design improvement. Do not use singleton and inject through the constructor. You will get

```
public class XyzInterceptor {
    private final int requestLimit;
    private final int responseLimit;
    
    public XyzInterceptor(LimitHealper limitHealper) {
        requestLimit = limitHealper.getLimits("fff");
        responseLimit = limitHealper.getLimits("fff");
    }

    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) {

        // Check if rate limit is disabled
        if (requestLimit == 0 && responseLimit == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        //logic inside

    }
}
```

so you test becomes

```
@Test
public void preHandelWhenLimitIsavailable() {
    LimitHealper limitHealper = mock(LimitHealper.class);
    expect(limitHealper.getLimits(anyObject(String.class))).andStubReturn(6000);
    replay(limitHealper);

    XyzInterceptor crrli = new XyzInterceptor(limitHealper);

    MockHttpServletRequest req = get("/customResource").buildRequest(new MockServletContext());
    MockHttpServletResponse resp = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    crrli.preHandle(req, resp, "doesn't matter");
    
    assertEquals(200,resp.getStatus());
}
```